# Angular compiled input is not working the same as non compiled

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to dynamically create inputs using angular directives and I am experiencing a few odd things when doing so. I have stripped down what I did to a simple [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/S5ByVTrgjufyIynOCvad?p=preview).

Index.html

```
<body ng-controller="mainController as vm">
  <h1>{{vm.title}}</h1>

  <input type="text" ng-model="vm.title" pu-elastic-input />
  <a-input this-is-for="title" />
</body>
```

script.js

```
(function() {
  angular
  .module('app', ['puElasticInput'])
  .controller('mainController', function mainController() {
    var vm = this;

    this.title = 'hello world!';
  })
  .directive('aInput', function($compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
        var input = angular.element('<input />');

        input.attr('type', 'text');
        input.attr('ng-model', 'vm.' + attributes['thisIsFor']);
        input.attr('pu-elastic-input', '');

        element.replaceWith($compile(input)(scope));
      },
    }
  });
}());
```

Essentially these two inputs should be the same size, however the compiled on (right) is larger than the one on the left. I am using angular-elastic-input for the dynamic sizing. I have noticed a few other things that did a similar thing, but these are part of the plunk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's a forked plunkr that works](http://plnkr.co/edit/AYCfs2VwnbjBtuaCErf7?p=preview), I've changed your `$compile` function so it uses the cloned node.

```
$compile(input)(scope, function(clone) {
    element.replaceWith(clone);
});
```

> cloneAttachFn - If cloneAttachFn is provided, then the link function will clone the template and call the cloneAttachFn function allowing the caller to attach the cloned elements to the DOM document at the appropriate place. The cloneAttachFn is called as:
>   cloneAttachFn(clonedElement, scope)

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks!